# Prefetching data in with Linq-to-SQL, IOC and Repository pattern

Tags: linq-to-sql, architecture, inversion-of-control, datacontext, prefetch

using Linq-to-SQL I'd like to prefetch some data.

1) the common solution is to deal with **DataLoadOptions**, but in my architecture it won't work because :

- the options have to be set before the first query
- I'm using IOC, so I don't directly instanciate the DataContext (I cannot execute code at instanciation)
- my DataContext is persistent for the duration of a web request

2) I have seen another possibility based on **loading** the **data and its childs** in a method, then returning only the data (so the child is already loaded) [see an example here](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/38838.aspx)

Nonetheless, in my architecture, it cannot not work :

- My queries are cascaded out of my repository and can be consumed by many services that will add clauses
- I work with interfaces, the concrete instances of the linq-to-sql objects do not leave the repositories (yes, you can work with interfaces AND add clauses)
- My repositories are generic

Yes, this architecture is quiet complicated, but it's very cool as I can play with the code like lego ;)

My question is : what are the **other possibilities** to prefetch a data ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my app i use perhaps a variation to your potential solution #2. It's somewhat difficult to explain but simply: i chain and defer lazy loading in my model with custom [lazy classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1669607/is-this-repository-pattern-efficient-with-linq-to-sql/1695561#answer-1695561) so as to abstract away from the LinqToSql-specific Differed Execution that i take advantage of with `IQueryable`. Benefits:

- My Domain Model and Service layer upwards does not necessarily have to depend on the LinqToSql provider (i can swap out my DAL with interfaces if i want to)
- My Service methods can and do return complete object graphs with multiple 'anchor points' for lazy loading using classes that abstract away a particular lazy loading implementation - so i can use LinqToSql-specific Differed Execution or something else (eg. anon delegates. again, refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1669607/is-this-repository-pattern-efficient-with-linq-to-sql/1695561#answer-1695561))
- I can maintain `IQueryable` results throughout my app (even to the UI if i want to) thus allowing infinite LINQ query chaining without having to worry about performance.

Comment: Thanks, it's a very interesting solution. It's centred on the data object, which I find better. Unfortunately it doesn't answer my current need as my whole architecture is based on lazy loading and the fetched properties are the exception ! I will however try to create a FetchItem<T> and FetchList<T> based on this 'data-object-centric' way of writing, because I really like it. I'm thinking about using attributes to auto-generated the 'CustomDCParameter' class I was talking before. I'll share if I find an acceptable solution (when I have time to work on it). Still listening for good advices

Comment: I think you may be misunderstanding me - when you say 'fetched' do you mean immediate loading from the db? as opposed to lazy/delay loading?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of other possibilities, it seems like you've pushed LinqToSql to its limits (I may be wrong, however).

I think your best options at this point are:

1. Add some "non-generic" methods to your application to handle just the
   specific scenarios where you want/need eager loading and don't
   use your "normal", "generic" infrastructure for those methods.
2. Use an ORM that has more sophisticated support for eager and lazy loading.

Comment: Thanks for your answers

1) I can put some non generic code, but the real problem is that I really want my layers to be separated. My queries are manipulated by the service layer and the database call is triggered by them (transparently), and I don't want to add trick code into them ;)

Loose coupling must be paid :p

2) You may be right. It's too late for the current project, but for the next one I'll do some testing with other ORM. Any advise ? Ideally something compliant with linq would be great (I really enjoy using it)

Comment: Loose coupling sometimes comes at a cost of increased complexity.  It's your choice how you want to make that tradeoff.  NHibernate has sophisticated support for eager and lazy loading and also supports Linq, but there may be other ORMs that meet those requirements as well.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution.
My answer is '**Dependency injection**'.

It's generally shipped with IOC, and mean you can have your IOC container manage injection of classes at instanciation.

All I need is to inject a ***CustomDCParameter*** class when I instanciate a DC.
That class will contains the rules, and the constructor will apply all of them.